# how do I set up Opus for Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, opus

I am trying to setup Opus for Discord.py for a bot I been trying to make. The basic concept of the bot is to play an audio when I do -play. Here is my current code for the bot that you'll need:

````py
voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if voice_channel != None:
        channel = voice_channel.name
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe("C:desktop/Welcome.m4a")
        vc.play(source)
        await vc.disconnect()```
````

Comment: what's wrong with it? what does the error and traceback look like?

Comment: @shark Nevermind about it, I got it working. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: you could answer your own question by explaining what you did to fix the issue. there may be others looking for some help as well. but glad you got it working!